# Is there a formal term for when a word begins to be used in a broader sense than the original sense?

Tags: terminology, language-change

For example: "aggressive recruitment", "aggressive cleaning" or "more aggressive guidelines".

Comment: The question is clear enough, but I'm not sure how your example is using the word in a broader sense?

Comment: The term aggressive i guess

Comment: Semantic widening?

Comment: Just to say that this usage of "aggressive" belongs to sub-standard English, basically advertising jargon. "Aggressive cleaning" works only as a deliberate joke.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by @guifa, a commonly used term is **semantic widening** (as opposed to **narrowing**), dating to Arsène Darmesteter (1887) at least and also used by Leonardo Bloomfield, Stephen Ullman and many others.  An equivalent term is **generalization** (as opposed to **specialization**), used by Paul Hermann (1880) and also by Bréal, Blank and many others.  Depending on the specific semantic theory, these technical terms may be given more specialized or narrower (*wink*) meanings.  [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change) has more examples.

Comment: Ha, I just took a stab based on semantic drift a term I'm more familiar with (hence my question mark). Didn't realize it was an established term :-)

Answer (score 2):

A term often used synonymously to "generalisation" is **bleaching**. Joan Bybee in his Cambridge Textbook in Linguistics on *Language Change* defines it as "a meaning change in which specific features of meaning are lost" (p. 267).